# how to connect angular 6 app with php and mysql of xammp server?

Tags: php, mysql

Actually, I'm developing an angular 6 app that connects and talks with PHP and MySQL. I'm using XAMPP server for PHP's localhost. In angular 6 apps, I created a proxyconfig,.json file in root directory and code looks like this.

```
{
  "/api":{
    "target" : "http://localhost:80",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin" : true
  }
}
```

And in my service file..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyserviceService {

  serviceData = '';
  date;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get('/api/json-app/employee.php');
  }
}
```

And the folder structure of PHP files in htdocs looks like this...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gr2e.png)

when I run my app, it says error 404 files not found...

what is the problem...

By the way, PHP file is in xammpp/htdocs/json-app/employee.php folder, Not on angular directory structure...

thanks in advance...